# How to Factor Out a Binomial From a Perfect Square Trinomial

Tags: polynomials, factoring, square-numbers

I understand how to factor a perfect square trinomial, but I am unable to see the steps taken to go from
$$2x(2x + 1) + (2x +1)$$
to
$$(2x +1)(2x +1)\text.$$

If you were asked to factor out $2x+1$ from the above expression, what steps would you take to transform it to
$$(2x +1)(2x +1)\text?$$

Also, what steps would I need to take to reverse the process? As in to go from
$$(2x +1)(2x+1)$$
back to
$$2x(2x + 1) + (2x +1)\text.$$

- I had a meaningful screen shot that I wanted to share but I don't have enough points to post an image (whack)

Comment: $2x(2x+1)+(2x+1) = 2x(2x+1) + 1(2x+1) = (2x+1)(2x+1)$

Answer (score 1):

**How to factor out 2x + 1 from the expression**

1. divide 2x + 1 from 2x(2x + 1) + 1(2x +1) = 2x + 1
2. Mulitply the divisor by the quotient = (2x +1)(2x + 1)

**How to revert the expression back to 2x(2x + 1) + (2x +1)**

1. use FOIL or the distributive property to multiply (2x + 1)(2x + 1)

(2x)^2 + 2x + 2x + 1 = 2x(2x + 1) + (2x +1)